# Is there an sql condition that can look for non integers in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

Basically I would like a select statement that would function like this

```
SELECT *
FROM table  
WHERE column IS NOT INT
```

Is there a condition like this or how do you check for non-integers in an nvarchar(10) column?

Comment: I deleted my answer as it was wrong...

Comment: =( but at least you got +30 in score =)

Comment: Is `'42.0'` considered an integer?

Comment: (And a badge! http://stackoverflow.com/badges/37/disciplined)

Comment: Good question, could you extend your answer to cover both alternatives?

Comment: What RDBMS? Are you only interested in positive integers?

Comment: I actually only have integers from 1-1000 or letters from a-z. But if you could cover both `42.0` and `-15` it would probably be of help to others with similar questions.

Comment: @Niklas: my query will match `42.0`, `-15` and `1E8`.

Comment: RDBMS? I use SQL Server.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In `SQL Server` you can do:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable  
WHERE   CASE WHEN IsNumeric(mycolumn) = 1 THEN CASE WHEN CAST(mycolumn AS FLOAT) <> CAST(CAST(mycolumn AS FLOAT) AS INT) THEN 1 END ELSE 1 END = 1
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean I get this error: `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'END'.`

Comment: This still gets errors for scientific notation (`1e4` or `2d6`)

Answer (score 16):

You could also use

```
SELECT  *
FROM    T 
WHERE  C = ''
        OR C LIKE '%[^0-9-]%' /*Contains a char other than - or 0-9*/
        OR C LIKE '_%-%'  /*Contains the - char other than 1st position*/
```

Comment: Need to exclude zero length fields also I think

Comment: Hard to pick a correct answer here. Yours will work in my specific case but Quassnoi's covers a wider range =/

Comment: I'd go for Quassnoi's as it is more general. Extending the `LIKE` to cover all cases would likely make it a fair bit more convoluted!

Comment: @Alex - Yep. Adjusted to cope with that and `-ve` integers.

Answer (score 0):

This is so weird

SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE Period_Year > 1900
AND Period_Month BETWEEN 1 AND 12

Fixed the problem.

the database has no value that are less or eqeul to 1900
and it has no months NOT BETWEEN 1 OR 12.

I also did a
SELECT DISTINCT ISDATE(CONCAT( Period_Year,'/',Period_Month,'/', 1))
FROM TABLE

I GOT A TRUE i.e 1 BACK

NO FALSE i.e 0 WHERE RETURNED

only 1 row with 1 for true

Even when I do
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE Period_Year > 1

this fixes the problem