# Show data where the value is after the decimal point

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to do (select value from table where...) where the value of a given experiment is not an integer, but it is decimal

Comment: OK, so you've told us what you want to do, but what is your question? What have you tried so far to solve the problem? I assume, as well, that your column is actually a `decimal` data type, as if you insert an `int` into a `decimal` column it'll be implicitly converted to a `decimal` (so `12`, would be evaluated to something like `12.0000` if you have a `decimal(6,4)`).

Comment: Your question is similar to this and it has an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789422/is-there-an-sql-condition-that-can-look-for-non-integers-in-a-column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an sql condition that can look for non integers in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789422/is-there-an-sql-condition-that-can-look-for-non-integers-in-a-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FLOOR` function to do this. It will round up your numbers, so you can pick only this that are not integers.

```
create table #t (i decimal(12,6))

insert into #t values (1), (1.1)

select * from #t where FLOOR(i) <> i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as

```
CREATE TABLE T( Val DECIMAL(10, 2));

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(10.10), (10);

SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE CAST(Val AS INT) <> Val
```

Returns: `10.10`